# Sunspot solr in rails need help to perform some query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I  have a model User and Listing in my rails app. User has many listings and listing belongs to user. I also have a attribute name rating in user table. What I want is to search the keyword in Listing model and order it based on rating attribute of User model.

This is what I have in Listing model

```
searchable do  
    text :title, :default_boost => 3  
    text :description, :default_boost => 2  
    integer :category_id, :references => Category  
    integer :subcategory_id, :references => Subcategory  
    string :zipcode  
    time :created_at  
        double :user do  
        user.rating  
    end  
end
```

And this is how I am trying to search

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Listing) do  
    keywords params[:q]  do   
        fields :title  
    end  
    order_by THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP    
    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the keyword and rating attributes to the listing searachable method.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  searchable do
    text :keyword
    integer :rating { user.rating }
  end
end
```

Then in your search action in your controller

```
Listing.search do
  fulltext params[:q]
  order_by :rating, :desc
end
```

See http://sunspot.github.com/ for more examples.

Looking at your code, you need to change in your searchable method

```
double :user do
  user.rating
end
```

to

```
double :rating do
  user.rating
end
```

Comment: for your rating, you have it defined as :user do...end when it should be :rating do...end

Comment: Hi Symana, thanks alot for your help. Now, I know exactly what I was missing. Instead doing   integer :rating {user.rating}, I have to do integer :rating do user.rating end incase someone is also searching for it –